# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 on INSERT/SELECT

Tags: database, sqlite, select, insert, cursor

first of all sorry for my horrible english.

I'm new on android world and now i have so much trouble with sqlite db:

when i try to execute this code:

```
public void signInOnDB(String name, String surname, String username, String password, String secretQuestion,
                          String secretAnswer, int g, int m, int a, String regione){
    String data = DateTime.setData(g, m, a);
    secretAnswer = secretAnswer.toLowerCase();

    database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO credenziali (userID, username, password, secretQuestion, secretAnswer) VALUES (null,'" + username + "','" + password + "','" + secretQuestion + "','" +
            secretAnswer + "');", null);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT userID FROM credenziali WHERE username =='"+ username + "';", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
    cursor.close();
    database.rawQuery("INSERT INTO utenti VALUES (" + id + ",'" + name + "','" + surname + "','" + regione + "','" + data + "');", null);
}
```

the program generate `the android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` when he arrive at `int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));`

I really don't have idea why generate exception, the query can't be null because I insert that value three lines up with the INSERT query.

If I execute that 3 queries on SQLite Browser the returned record is right.

Anyone can help me?

Invoking method:

```
databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        databaseAccess.signInOnDB(insert_name.getText().toString(), insert_surname.getText().toString(),
                insert_username.getText().toString(), insert_password1.getText().toString(), insert_secretQuestion.getText().toString(),
                insert_secretAnswer.getText().toString(), g, m, a, regionResidence);
        databaseAccess.close();'
```

Definition of open()/close():

```
/**
 * Open the database connection.
 */
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * Close the database connection.
 */
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}
```

Definition of openHelper:

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GDB.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I solved,

when i use INSERT/UPDATE query on database I need to use `.execSQL(string)` and not `rawQuery(string, ...)`